# How can I evaluate a stringified class method?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm serializing functions to send them over the network. They are then executed on the other side from their stringified form.

I can do this:

```
function test1() { console.log("test1") }
eval(`(${test1})`)()
```

I can also do this:

```
const test2 = function() { console.log("test2") }
eval(`(${test2})`)()
```

This also works:

```
const test3 = () => { console.log("test3") }
eval(`(${test3})`)()
```

(all of these produce different stringified versions of the functions)

**However, this fails:**

```
class A {
    test4() { console.log("test4") }
}
const a = new A
eval(`(${a.test4})`)()
```

The error is `Unexpected token {` because the stringified method is `test4() { console.log("test4") }` which is not a valid function declaration (it's neither named nor anonymous).

A static method does not solve the problem (same result).

My question is: what's the best way to send a class method over the network? Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're this but the last example will work with: `eval(\`(${a.test4()})\`);`.

Comment: You should probably do something more like `window.allMyCallableStuff = {test1: () => {console.log('test1')}}` and not use eval but `let varFuncName = 'test1'; window.allMyCallableStuff[varFuncName]();` I might not have the exact match for what you're trying to do but you can probably do without `eval`.